# JSF2.2Majorra & PF5.1: Custom date format in DataTable

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a page with a datatable

like so: http://s7.postimg.org/60qsj2z8b/datatable.png

the relevant part is this:

```
                <p:dataTable id="blockedPeriodTable" var="blockedPeriod"
                    value="#{blockedPeriodController.project.blockerList}"
                    emptyMessage="Keine Blocker gefunden"
                    style="width:50%;min-width:585px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;margin-bottom:20px"
                    rowKey="#{blockedPeriod.id}">
                    <f:facet name="header">Blockzeiten</f:facet>
                    <p:column headerText="Von" width="200">
                        <h:outputText value="#{blockedPeriod.startDateAsDate}">
                            <f:convertDateTime timeStyle="short" dateStyle="full"
                                timeZone="CET" type="both" />
                        </h:outputText>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Bis" width="200">
                        <h:outputText value="#{blockedPeriod.endDateAsDate}" >
                            <f:convertDateTime timeStyle="short" dateStyle="full"
                                timeZone="CET" type="both" />
                        </h:outputText>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Grund" style="width: 125px;">
                        <h:outputText value="#{blockedPeriod.reason}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
```

I have outputtexts which have a f:convertDateTime inside them determining how the dates show

now as you can see in the picture, times are shown as 00:00, 12:00 and 23:59

instead of 'Sonntag, 20. Dezember 2015 12:00' the goal is to show something like 'Sonntag, 20. Dezember 2015 mittags'

this cant be done with convertDateTime afaik, and I don't want to use JavaScript for it

I don't really know how to do it...

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a perfectly working solution, that still keeps everything nice and dynamic

```
<h:outputText rendered="#{blockedPeriod.endDate.hour==12}" value=" mittags" />
```

and i changed the convertdatetimes to not show the time at all

now looking like this

http://s15.postimg.org/phm955c6j/datatable.png

Comment: Better extend the standard date time converter (and localize it). By the way, what happened with Deutsche Gründlichkeit? Those posts contain terribly a lot of missing capitalization and punctuation.

Comment: i find this to be a pretty easy solution
but ill do some fiddling around with the standard datetime converter when i have time

hahaha deutsche gründlichkeit? ich bin schweizer ;)

Comment: Well, what happened to the Swiss precision then? The one that made their clocks and watches worldfamous?;-)

Comment: damn dudes... I will try to capitalize correctly from now on. Apparently thats really important here...